# Disable all Run time error messages in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, show, message

what is most standard and simple way to tell a prevent Delphi program to show ANY message windows when user run the exe?

for example this is my program with a web browser object, when site have errors that Geko component showing errors to user... i want to stop it.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, OleCtrls, MOZILLACONTROLLib_TLB;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MozillaBrowser1: TMozillaBrowser;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MozillaBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.xeex.ir');
end;

end.
```

Comment: This isn't a Delphi question so much as a Gecko question

Comment: no that's just a sample. i want to disable all errors in a delphi project... that was exact case of mine as a sample.

Comment: Try-Except-End is not acceptable?

Comment: What you're asking is a really bad idea. It results in programs that quietly do nothing and the user has no idea why. You might need to manage those errors better, and provide user-friendly error messages. But simply "disabling error messages" is like sweeping the broken vase under the rug and pretending the big lump isn't there.

Comment: You can't turn off errors totally. You can catch exceptions, or fix your code to deal with issues properly. Burying your head in the sand to avoid seeing the problems is useless.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do what you ask in general. You cannot apply a setting that will stop all error dialogs being shown.

For native Delphi exceptions, you can choose to ignore them if you wish. Not that that would be a good idea. For message boxes shown by third party code you need that code to offer a way to suppress those errors. If that mechanism exists, you can of course use it. But if no mechanism exists then you are out of luck. And every different library will use separate mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you so much David, so i have to go and ask exact way to stop errors for Geko then?

Comment: What about this question? You asked how to stop all errors.